# Xamarin Webview com angular

Tags: ios, xamarin, webview

Tenho um WebView renderizando um site em angular, porem em algumas páginas ele funciona sem problemas e em outras não, quando efetuo um post ele da erro de

> XMLHttpRequest  due to access control checks.

Coloquei as excessões dentro do **info.plist** mas não resolveu.
No Android o projeto roda sem nenhum problema. O problema ocorre com iOS

Comment: resolvido, era a forma de como efetuava o map do response dentro do meu service-proxy.

Comment: Escreve a resposta como voce fez e marca como respondida, aí ajuda os próximos que pesquisarem ( no campo de resposta abaixo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvido, era a forma de como efetuava o map do response dentro do meu service-proxy.